# Can't locate in @INC Perl perl file loaded by "require"

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a simple Perl script that uses helper functions located in another file `common.pl`:

#### main.pl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd 'abs_path';

use File::Basename qw( fileparse );
use File::Path qw( make_path );
use File::Spec;


require "common.pl";  # line 15

#...
```

#### common.pl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub getTimeLoggerHelper{
  #....
}

1;
```

Locally everything runs well, but when I try to run it through ssh I get an error:

```
Can't locate common.pl in @INC  (@INC contains: 
/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level  /Library/Perl/5.18 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.18 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /Users/snaggs/scripts/main.pl line 15.
```

#### [EDIT 1]

If I log in to a remote machine and run the same script, then there are no errors.

#### [EDIT 2]

I also tried converting `common.pl` to a module:

#### common.pm

```perl
package Common;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub getTimeLoggerHelper{
  #....
}

1;
__END__
```

and from `main.pl` I call it like this

```perl
use Module::Load;
load Common;
```

Same problem, locally works, from ssh - same error:

```
Can't locate Common.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Common module)
```

How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: There is no `load` in Perl. That's a syntax error. Where is the common.pl file located?

Comment: @simbabque in the same folder where `main.pl`

Comment: @simbabque: `load` is provided by `Module::Load`, which is imported on the preceding line.

Comment: @borodin I see. I think I was still asleep. Happy new year! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to use `require` for this, supply the full path

```
require "/full/path/to/common.pl";
```

This is needed over `ssh` even if the file is in the same directory with the script, because over `ssh` the `.` in `@INC` is *not* the script's directory (since the working directory, `.`, is likely your `$HOME`). This happens in other cases, as well.<sup>†</sup>

Note that this way you are importing *everything* that is in `common.pl`.

There are many advantages to using a proper module instead. Then the file is `.pm` and by convention the file name is capitalized (and Pascal-cased).

Here is a bare-bones example with files `bin/main.pl` and `lib/Common.pm`

**bin/main.pl**

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use FindBin 1.51 qw($RealBin);  # Directory in which the script is
use lib "$RealBin/../lib";      # Where modules are, relative to $RealBin

use Common qw(test_me);

test_me();
```

The critical part of setting up `@INC`, where modules are looked for,
is done with [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma. It adds directories to the beginning of the default `@INC`, at compile time. The [FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html)'s `$RealBin` is the script's directory, with links resolved. We use it so that added paths are relative to the script and not hard-coded. This helps source organization when script and its libraries come together.

Another way to set this up is via the [environment variable `PERL5LIB`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT). With `bash`

```
export PERL5LIB=/path/to/libdir
```

Then for a `Module.pm` that is in that `libdir` you only need to say `use Module` and it will be found. This is useful for modules that live at a particular location, to be used by various scripts.

**lib/Common.pm**

```
package Common;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( test_me );

sub test_me { print "Hello from ", __PACKAGE__, "\n" }

1;
```

When a package is [use](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)d its file is first [require](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html)d and then the module's [import](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html#import-LIST) method runs, at compile time.  It is via `import` that the caller actually gets the symbols (names for  functions and variables) defined in the module, and we must provide an `import` method in our module (or use fully qualified names, `Module::function`, in a caller).

The line with `use Exporter` brings in *its* `import` routine, so we don't have to write our own. With old versions of [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) this was used via inheritance, often by `@ISA = ('Exporter')`. See docs.

Then symbols are made available via `@EXPORT_OK`. This requires a caller to list functions to be used; it does not "push" anything into their namespace by default.  There is also `%EXPORT_TAG` which is helpful, specially if the list of symbols that callers import grows long.

---

<sup>†</sup>  This is really just one example of a general problem with using the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (`.`) for the script's directory: it isn't; in general it just isn't.

Another thing to note, since version 5.26 the `.` (current directory) [is not anymore](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5260delta#Removal-of-the-current-directory-(%22.%22)-from-@INC) in `@INC`, for security reasons.  This may have also been backported to earlier versions.

So just use `$RealBin`, like shown (the version 1.51 had an important fix).

Comment: I did, I tried to load `Common.pm` as module, see my Edit2.

Comment: @snaggs That is not a correct way to write a module, as you are not setting up a system to export symbols. As for the script, why are you using `Module::Load` at all?  Once the module is set up all you need is `use Common qw(functions);`.  (You want to call modules with upper case, `Common.pm` for this one.) Let me know if you want to switch to this.  But this change in `require` line should make it work, for starters.

Comment: It's probably better to recommend `use Exporter 'import'` rather than the superseded inheritance method. Older versions of `Exporter` don't support it, but inheriting `import` instead of importing it should be seen as a work-around for those unwilling or unable to upgrade.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for the recommendation.  I have to go now while I wanted to put out a reasonable example.  Certainly need to add to this (and to edit).

Comment: @Borodin I usually don't export anything when writing modules and instead always call functions with their fully qualified name: `use Common; my $rc = Common::getTimeLoggerHelper();`. I prefer it because a) it doesn't pollute the namespace and b) I always exactly know where the `getTimeLoggerHelper` comes from. But perhaps that's just personal habit.

Comment: @PerlDuck: You shouldn't be policing the namespace of other people's
programs: the author of the calling code should have 
a say in whether they want their namespace polluted. 
And it is a useful way of documenting by implication which of the
subroutines in your library you expect to be most useful.
Depending on the nature of your library, there may be two or three calls
to fully-qualified identifiers in a single statement, and refusing
the author access to the obvious abbreviation will make their code unnecessarily unreadable just because of your fixation.

Comment: @Borodin  Thank your for the note on Exporter ways, edited.

Comment: @PerlDuck That's a reasonable policy (while it is also reasonable to drop all the typing).  That's why I use `@EXPORT_OK` -- it does not actually export things (does not change symbol tables) while it does make symbols available for import, so the caller can decide. The can still opt to _not import_ and use fully qualified names.  I don't see a drawback to _providing_ this. It doesn't enforce anything on anyone.

Comment: @snaggs  I edited, with comments and links.  Please let me know if more/other/better would be useful.

Comment: @zdim: I agree. The issue with exporting *nothing* is that the calling code has no options other than using the fully-qualified identifier or messing with the symbol table. The [charnames](https://metacpan.org/pod/charnames) pragma is like this. It provides various subroutines that must be called as, for example, `charnames::string_vianame('LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK')`. Because `Exporter` isn't used, the calling code has to use the awful `*string_vianame = \&charnames::string_vianame` to import the name explicitly.

Comment: I've never seen it _that_ way, @Borodin. Thank you. Depending on its purpose, I'll consider the use of \@EXPORT_OK next time, like zdim does. It sounds very reasonable.

Comment: @Borodin  Right, good example.  Another example is of some `::Tiny` modules, which don't export in order to remain within the `::Tiny` specs. I forget the particular one, which is well known and good ... but I was a bit turned off by this.

Comment: @zdim: There's a specification for `Tiny` modules?

Comment: @Borodin  Well, restrictions on code size (and memory footprint?) so that it may go as `::Tiny`. I am not sure how strict it is, perhaps "specification" is too strong of a term. I forget what it was, I think I saw that information in the particular module that I can't recall, explaining why it doesn't set up exports. It may have been in comparison with a full fledged module which functionality the `::Tiny` version implements.

Comment: @zdim: Okay, thank you. I'll look around. Please let me know if you find a reference. It would be nice if the categories *did* have a specification. At present it is more difficult than it should be to locate a module that serves a purpose and works well.

Comment: @Borodin  I only found [File::Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Path-Tiny/lib/File/Path/Tiny.pod), which calls upon [Acme::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/Acme-Tiny-0.6/lib/Acme/Tiny.pod), which has a reference to [a blog](http://blogs.perl.org/users/dan_muey/2014/08/please-dont-use-tiny-unless-it-meets-the-tiny-criteria-thanks.html).  Skimming through only revealed rules set forth by Adam Kenedy.  Hardly formal :(  There may be more?